# Merging on columns with dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a simple script currently written with pandas that I want to convert to dask dataframes.
In this script, I am executing a merge on two dataframes on user-specified columns and I am trying to convert it into dask.

```
def merge_dfs(df1, df2, columns):
    merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=columns, how='inner')
...
```

How can I change this line to match to dask dataframes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dask` merge follows `pandas` syntax, so it's just substituting call to `pandas` with a call to `dask.dataframe`:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

def merge_dfs(df1, df2, columns):
    merged = dd.merge(df1, df2, on=columns, how='inner')
# ...
```

The resulting dataframe, `merged`, will be a `dask.dataframe` and hence may need computation downstream. This will be done automatically if you are persisting the data to a file, e.g. with `.to_csv` or with `.to_parquet`.

If you will need the dataframe for some computation and if the data fits into memory, then calling `.compute` will create a `pandas` dataframe:

```py
pandas_df = merged.compute()
```